# How to add featured products slider (numerous featured products) on volusion?

Tags: jquery, slider, e-commerce, volusion

I am working on volusion ecommerce site. Does anyone know how to add featured product slider on volusion site? The slider will display numerous products (Like featured products or brands) on the horizontal line. There are arrow buttons (Like Left to right) on each side for people to navigate. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While there are dozens of jQuery based sliders/slideshows out there to use perhaps the built in version offered by Volusion may suit your needs.

http://support.volusion.com/article/homepage-slideshow

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just edit my question. I forgot to mention for featured products. The volusion slider link you gave is for the main slider.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Volusion to display featured products and mark your desired products as featured.
Then use JavaScript to find and modify the featured products html as necessary for the slider code that you choose. Run that code prior to the slider code.